# Inequality with characteristic functions

Tags: integration, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> Let $\varphi(t) $ be a characteristic function of some random variable.  Proof the following inequality: $$ \left| \frac{1}{2h} \int\limits_{t-h}^{t+h} \varphi(u) d u \right| \le \left(1 + \text{Re}\: \varphi(h) \right)^{1/2}$$

I tried to rewrite it somehow, but I failed all attempts. I will be very greatful if you help!

Comment: Potential idea: write $\varphi(u) = E[e^{iuX}] = \int_{x\in\text{dom}(X)} e^{iux}p_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$, then apply Fubini's theorem to switch the order of integration and try to simplify stuff.